# What is the solution to the second-order nonlinear differential equation $y'' = a y'^2 + b y + c x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can you give me a hint about how I can solve the second-order nonlinear differential equation $$y'' = a  y'^2 + b y + c  x~? $$

**Context:** When you write the Bellman equation of a drift rate control problem (of a one-dimensional Brownian motion) with a discounted criterion, you get a second-order differential equation of the form above. Finding a closed-form solution to this differential equation would help in solving the drift rate control problem.

Comment: There is no reason to think this has a closed form solution.  (If $b=0$ it can be solved in terms of Airy functions Ai and Bi.)

Comment: Thank you, GEdgar. The case with $b = 0$ arises under the average-cost criterion. I am particularly interested in the case where $b \neq 0$, which corresponds to the discounted Bellam equation. Also, the term $cx$ can be substituted with any strictly increasing function of $x$ (if that helps).

Answer (score 1):

It can be "reduced" to a first order equation: if you write $t = y/c + x/b$ and use 
$t$ as the independent variable and $v = dx/dt$ as dependent variable, the equation becomes
$$ v' = - \left(bt + \frac{ac}{b^2}\right) v^3 + \frac{2 ac}{b} v^2 - ac v $$

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a,b,c\neq0$ for the key case:

Hint:

Let $u=y+\dfrac{cx}{b}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{dy}{dx}+\dfrac{c}{b}$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}=a\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}-\dfrac{c}{b}\right)^2+bu$

$\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}=a\left(\dfrac{du}{dx}\right)^2-\dfrac{2ac}{b}\dfrac{du}{dx}+\dfrac{ac^2}{b^2}+bu$

Let $v=\dfrac{du}{dx}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\dfrac{dv}{dx}=\dfrac{dv}{du}\dfrac{du}{dx}=v\dfrac{dv}{du}$

$\therefore v\dfrac{dv}{du}=av^2-\dfrac{2acv}{b}+\dfrac{ac^2}{b^2}+bu$

$\left(bu+av^2-\dfrac{2acv}{b}+\dfrac{ac^2}{b^2}\right)\dfrac{du}{dv}=v$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $w=u+\dfrac{av^2}{b}-\dfrac{2acv}{b^2}+\dfrac{ac^2}{b^3}$ ,

Then $u=w-\dfrac{av^2}{b}+\dfrac{2acv}{b^2}-\dfrac{ac^2}{b^3}$

$\dfrac{du}{dv}=\dfrac{dw}{dv}-\dfrac{2av}{b}+\dfrac{2ac}{b^2}$

$\therefore bw\left(\dfrac{dw}{dv}-\dfrac{2av}{b}+\dfrac{2ac}{b^2}\right)=v$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dv}-\left(\dfrac{2av}{b}-\dfrac{2ac}{b^2}\right)w=\dfrac{v}{b}$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dv}=\dfrac{2a}{b}\left(v-\dfrac{c}{b}\right)w+\dfrac{v}{b}$

Let $s=v-\dfrac{c}{b}$ ,

Then $w\dfrac{dw}{ds}=\dfrac{2asw}{b}+\dfrac{s}{b}+\dfrac{c}{b^2}$

Let $t=\dfrac{as^2}{b}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dw}{ds}=\dfrac{dw}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{ds}=\dfrac{2as}{b}\dfrac{dw}{dt}$

$\therefore\dfrac{2asw}{b}\dfrac{dw}{dt}=\dfrac{2asw}{b}+\dfrac{s}{b}+\dfrac{c}{b^2}$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dt}=w+\dfrac{1}{2a}+\dfrac{c}{2abs}$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dt}=w+\dfrac{1}{2a}\pm\dfrac{c}{2\sqrt ab\sqrt b\sqrt t}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf or in http://www.iaeng.org/IJAM/issues_v43/issue_3/IJAM_43_3_01.pdf